# External User can't "Copy to/Move to" other site - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, move, copy, move-to

For some reason, external users can't "Copy to/Move to" another site. They have Write permissions in both sites. When they try to search for more sites it doesn't show anything:

[image]

When I try the same with an internal user it works well.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How long has the external user existed? Is this immediately after accepting their invitation and logging in?

Comment: The external user exists since the SharePoint was created (1 year ago).

Comment: That's interesting, are they able to use search?

Comment: Yes, they are able to use search.

Comment: If the permissions are correct, then it's likely that you need to open a ticket with Microsoft support.

Comment: Alright. Thank you!